# StackExchange Redis Install in BOTH WebApp and Class Library

Tags: stackexchange.redis

We have an MVC5 WebApp and several class libraries all part of the same solution.

The WebApp is in Azure and we are using the StackExchange Redis as our caching.

We wanted to know if it is ok to also add the Exchange Redis package to one of our class libraries that also needs to access the Cache (we cannot reference the main web app as it would cause a circular reference) and create a separate Multiplexer in the library to access the same Cache/Database - and will there be any conflicts if the 2 Mutltiplexers are hiting the same Cache/Database with multiple users.
Many thanks